# How to use a WHERE clause with a GROUP BY

Tags: where

I'm learning SQL so apologies if this is too basic a question. I can't seem to figure out how to use a WHERE clause after I GROUP BY a field.

[image]

For example, how would I filter the results using a WHERE clause to only see those countries where the Order count is greater than 100?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to filter by an aggregated field after the result of a grouping (`GROUP BY` clause), there is a keyword called `HAVING` that you can use. The `HAVING` clause is specified after the `GROUP BY` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT
    orders.billing_country AS 'Country',
    count(orders.billing_country) AS 'Order count's
FROM
    orders
GROUP BY 
    orders.billing_country
HAVING 
    count(orders.billing_country) > 100;
```

The `WHERE` clause can only be used against columns before they're aggregated, which is why you can't use it in this case. It would be possible in a secondary step to use a `WHERE` clause if you wrapped your query in a CTE or subquery, or staged the results in a temporary table. But such an extra step isn't necessary here when `HAVING` logically does what you're asking for, in a single step.

Answer (score -3):

The clause is

```
where orders.Order_count > 100
```

And it goes just before the `group by`

Comment: This is incorrect  - see @J.D.'s answer!